# Web view: Returning nil at loadRequest while true in URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, url, webview, urlrequest

Web view: Returning nil at loadRequest while true in URLRequest

I don't know where is wrong.

import UIKit

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var designatedWebView: UIWebView!

    var webview: UIWebView!
    var testString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        designatedWebView = webview
        testString = "http://www.apple.com"

        let baseURL = URL(string: testString)
        let baseURLRequest = URLRequest(url: baseURL!) //this prints true
        designatedWebView.loadRequest(baseURLRequest)  //while this prints nil

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `designatedWebView = webview` statement?

Comment: What do you mean with "this prints nil", func loadRequest(_ request: URLRequest) has no return value

Comment: Did you intend to have two separate UIWebViews? Is `designatedWebView` from storyboard?

Comment: @R P Trying to connect to another view controller. I temporarily disconnected with that though.
Oh........ I deleted them and fixed it. lol
Thanks

Comment: @OliverM yes: a typical "fatal nil"

Comment: @KaylaGalway I tried to have a two separate web views, but 'designatedWebView' is from the same storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this. This is the normal and easiest way to load a website in UIWebView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com")

    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webView.loadRequest(request)

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
 }
}
```

If you are not connecting the webView from your Main.storyboard, then add this line of code with the above code in your viewDidLoad() function.

```
webView.delegate = self
```